# Python - Module level variables vs Function parameter?

Tags: python

```
def doSomething()
   bucket = s3.get_bucket(BUCKET_NAME)
   ...

if __name__=="__main__":
    s3 = boto.connect_s3()
    doSomething()
```

vs

```
def doSomething(s3)
   bucket = s3.get_bucket(BUCKET_NAME)
   ...

if __name__=="__main__":
    s3 = boto.connect_s3()
    doSomething(s3)
```

Is there a best-practice for this kind of a scenario? This is still a simple scenario. Sometimes there are 4-5 such variables which would need to be used on `doSomething`, and I've never developed a consistent style for dealing with these.

Comment: Module level variables have all the same issues as globals, which are bad for a myriad of reasons. Use sparing if at all.

Comment: The first example is invalid if not called as `main`.

Answer (score 2):

i would go with function parameters as it becomes easier to test the functions with easier mocks.

Also documentation and reuse becomes better

Comment: Or even better - if you have a set of functions which all depend on related data values, define a class.